# ASP MVC: Getting checked checkbox value and getting sum of input hidden when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am creating a ASP page with table form for a pre-enrollment system where the contents are as follows:

Column 1: Grades

Column 2: Checkbox (value is dynamically generated from SQL Server)together with a Input hidden (value is equal to the subject units)

Column 3: Subject Code

Column 4: Subject Description

Column 5: Subject Units

Column 6: Subject Pre-requisite

The view of the page is here:
[Page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLPZM.jpg)

What I want to happen is to get the sum of the checked checkbox through the value of input hidden that goes after the checkbox. Since the value of the checkbox (subject code) will be used in the post.

Here is the format of the checkbox and hidden:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="BSCS" value="@courses.course_code" onchange="checkUnits()" style="height:16px; width:16px;" />
<input type="hidden" name="BSCS_units" value="@courses.subject_unit" />
```

I tried to use javascript and it display on the text field the value "NaN"

Here is the script:

```
<script>
function checkUnits() {
    document.AdvisingForm.total.value = '';
    var sum = 0;
    var maxUnits = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.maxUnit))";
    for (i = 0; i < document.AdvisingForm.BSCS.length; i++) {
        if (document.AdvisingForm.BSCS[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.AdvisingForm.BSCS_units[i].value);

            if (sum >= +maxUnits + 2) {
                alert("You have already exceeded the maximum number of units required for this semester. Remove one of the courses selected to proceed on next step.");
                $('#course-BSCS').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#course-BSCS').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }      
    }

    document.AdvisingForm.total.value = sum;
}
</script>
```

I'm really confused with the script part. How can I accomplish this one. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what you meant by sum of checked checkbox ??? do you want to take the sum of all subject_unti where the checkbox is checked ?

Comment: so when you check each checkbox you have to increment a variable, in simple words you need to get the total number of checked checkboxes am i right?

Comment: from where did we get number of units of the subjects ?? when the uni of the subject need to increment ?? why units always the same value like 3 in pic ? what is the relation between unit and the checkbox??

Comment: The number of units is also dynamically generated from database. What needs to increment is only the text field that gets the total sum of the units. Usually all subjects in colleges especially minor subjects are 3 units only which is equivalent to 1.5 hours of lecture. The relation between the unit and the checkbox is that I need to set only a maximum number of units to be taken by a student to avoid overloading of subjects to be taken, this case are for irregular students. So checking up a checkbox need to increment the value of total units.

Comment: so the thing is may be you have a limited number of units for a student, and for each subject you have some units, and based on subject you have to count the total units right ???

Comment: Yes, precisely that is the idea of my problem

Comment: then this is the not the right way to do this,you have to specify one hidden field for each subject and this hidden field have different ids, and you have to trigger onchange event of checkbox and in this event you have to check  what are the checkobxes are checked and then take the corresponding hidden value (you can give hidden field id respect to checkboxid then it will be easy to get , then add those hidden values and validate it

Comment: Can you give me some code snippet so that I can have an idea on how should I start with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understands your problem correctly then the below example helps you to solve the issue.

You have to give an id field to each checkbox and hidden field associated with that like below.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ChkCourceCls" name="BSCS" id="@("chkbox_" + courses.course_code)" value="@courses.course_code" onchange="checkUnits()" style="height:16px; width:16px;" />
<input type="hidden" name="BSCS_units" id="@("hdnSubjectUnit_" + courses.course_code)" value="@courses.subject_unit" />
```

You can specify your checkbox and hidden field like above then in the onchange event of checkbox you can find the value of the particular hidden field assigned with that.

And in JS

```
function checkUnits() {
var yourarray = [];

$('input.ChkCourceCls[type=checkbox]').each(function () {


 if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  yourarray.push($(this).val());// in this array you got all cource code of subjects that are checked by the user.
}

}
var arylen=yourarray.length;
var ToalSubjectunit=0;
for(var i=0;i<arylen;i++)
{
 ToalSubjectunit+= parseInt($("#hdnSubjectUnit_"+yourarray[i]).val());
}
alert(ToalSubjectunit)// here you got the total unit of subject , based on this you can do your validations

}
```

note :You can also use name attribute  instead of class name. I have provided only a sample code , you can make changes in this code based on your logic and requirements

Comment: i got zero as result whenever i check a checkbox

Comment: try to alert the array size and let me know what is the length of the array

Comment: ok so the count of array is based on the checked checkboxes right??

Comment: try the code now there was a small mistake in the place where getting value from the hidden field.missed to add # symbol before id name

Comment: you can use parseInt for that , i had edited the answer pls check it out

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
var maxUnits = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.maxUnit))";
```

maxUnits variable stores a **string**. You can not use a string value for a numerical comparison.

```
var maxUnits = "450";
var newVal = maxUnits + 2
alert(newVal);
```

You will see an alert `"4502"` , not `452` !

Remove the double quotes.

```
var maxUnits = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.maxUnit));
```

I am not sure why you are doing Json.Encode on the ViewBag item. But if you set an integer value to the `ViewBag.maxUnit` in your action method like  `ViewBag.maxUnit = 4445;` you can directly access that in your javascript(*inside razor view*) like this

```
var maxUnits = @ViewBag.maxUnit;
alert(maxUnits);
```

Also, You actually do not need the hidden field. You can store the value you currently keeping inside the hidden value in html5 data attibutes on the checkbox input field itself.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-unit="@courses.subject_unit" 
                                  name="BSCS" value="@courses.course_code" />
```

I removed the onchange javasript call as we will handle the change event in an unobutrisive javascript way.

Listen to the `change` event on these specific inputs(*i used the name value as the jQuery selector*)

```
$(function() {
    var maxUnits = @ViewBag.maxUnit;
    $("input[name='BSCS']").change(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $("input[name='BSCS']:checked").each(function(a, b) {
            sum += parseInt($(this).data("unit"));

            // Keep in mind that this if condition is going to execute in the loop, 
            // you may consider moving it outside of the loop as well.

            if (sum >= maxUnits + 2) {
               alert("You have already exceeded.");
               $('#course-BSCS').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            else {
               $('#course-BSCS').removeAttr('disabled');
            }

        });
        $("#total").html(sum);
    });

});
```

Comment: I used the Json.Encode on the ViewBag.item since I get the value of the max number of units from the controller before the page loads. I tried to use @ViewBag.maxUnit yet the value is not stored to the variable. Or maybe there is something wrong with my controller.

Anyway,thanks for this, I will be trying this as soon as arrive home. Will be updating you on what will happen. Again, thanks a lot.